# What is the proper way to update my label's text from a function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, didset

I am trying to have my UILabel's text automatically update in increments of 1 based on a looping Timer. The label is linked to a variable. I'm not sure if it matters but I am doing my UI programmatically using auto layout anchors.

I understand this is not working because the variable lives outside of ViewDidLoad(). I also tried setting up a subclass of a UILabel in a separate file but I could not figure out the proper way to do that. I was having trouble connecting the variable to the subclass and properly implementing didSet.

Here is the relevant code from my View Controller, any recommendations or alternative methods are appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOfBreaths = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let breathCounter = UILabel()
        breathCounter.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        breathCounter.text = "\(numberOfBreaths)"
        breathCounter.textAlignment = .center
        breathCounter.center = self.view.center

        // Irrelevant hidden label code redacted

        let startStop = RoundButton()
        startStop.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        startStop.backgroundColor = .white
        startStop.setTitle("breathe", for: .normal)
        startStop.setTitleColor(.darkGray , for: .normal)
        startStop.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
        startStop.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 225, green: 225, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        startStop.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.breathCount), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(breathCounter)
        view.addSubview(holdTimer)
        view.addSubview(startStop)

        // Anchor code redacted
    }

    @objc func breathCount(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        print("Button Tapped")
        createTimer()
    }
    
    func createTimer() {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.5, target: self, selector: #selector(nextBreath), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func nextBreath() {
        numberOfBreaths += 1
        breathCounter.text = "\(numberOfBreaths)" // Error: Cannot find 'breathCounter' in scope
        print(numberOfBreaths) // Prints expected number to console
    }

}
```

[View for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gufr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare `breathCounter` as a property on your view controller (like you did for `numberOfBreaths`, you will have access to it from both the `viewDidLoad` and `nextBreath` functions. I'd also hold a reference to your `Timer`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOfBreaths = 0
    let breathCounter = UILabel()
    var timer : Timer?
```

And then inside `viewDidLoad`, remove the existing `let breathCounter = UILabel()` line.

And inside `createTimer`:

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.5, target: self, selector: #selector(nextBreath), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your feedback and the other user's response helped me solve my problem and get a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You error message: `// Error: Cannot find 'breathCounter' in scope` gives a good clue... it's all about scope.

You declare your `UILabel` within the `ViewDidLoad()` method and so that's where it lives; that's its scope. As soon as `ViewDidLoad` completes, *poof * `UILabel` disappears from memory.

What you need to do is move your `let breathCounter = UILabel()` outside of ViewDidLoad so it gets created along with your ViewController; then you will be able to reference it as long as your ViewController exists in memory.

Comment: You could also post a notification inside your function, with an observer function in your view controller which hold the label outlet